# Cron service won't start in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cron

Noticed my cron jobs weren't running (not sure for how long, maybe since I upgraded to 16.04 two weeks ago), and I can't get the service to start.

```
root@wormhole:~# systemctl start cron.service
Job for cron.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status cron.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@wormhole:~# systemctl status cron.service
● cron.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cron; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-02-20 23:02:57 EST; 6s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 8340 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cron start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 20 23:02:57 wormhole cron[8340]: Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
Feb 20 23:02:57 wormhole cron[8340]: utility, e.g. service cron start
Feb 20 23:02:57 wormhole cron[8340]: initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
Feb 20 23:02:57 wormhole cron[8340]: Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Feb 20 23:02:57 wormhole cron[8340]: Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start cron
Feb 20 23:02:57 wormhole cron[8340]: start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
Feb 20 23:02:57 wormhole systemd[1]: cron.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 20 23:02:57 wormhole systemd[1]: Failed to start cron.service.
Feb 20 23:02:57 wormhole systemd[1]: cron.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 20 23:02:57 wormhole systemd[1]: cron.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: The error messages seem to indicate that cron was attempting to communicate with Upstart, which was replaced by systemd in 16.04. Did your upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, by chance, have any errors?

Comment: @user535733 Yep sure did. Had to boot into a liveCD and re-install `init` to get it to boot after the upgrade

Comment: Have you run `apt-get install --fix-missing` and `dpkg configure -a` to clean up any un-upgraded packages? My first thought is that you might still be using the older version of cron.

Comment: No I hadn't. I just did and it didn't change anything but your comment prompted me to upgrade cron with `apt-get install cron` which fixed the issue. Makes me wonder what else in this install might be broken now though. Everything seems to be workin g...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 was not completely successful, leaving me with an old version of cron. The fix was:

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install cron
```